# What are limitations of using a sub-network setup?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, port-forwarding

Typically with personal WiFi, you have your ISP line into the home which connects to a modem, then a router (or hybrid of both). Then the router produces a network.

But now let's say you take an Ethernet cable form the first router (we'll call this network A) and connect it to a new router (we'll call this network B). Instead of extending the network, you use it to setup an entirely new WiFi network.

Setup shown here:
[image: Sub-Network Setup]

**So my question[s] is...**

1. Does Network B act as sort of a sub-network or is it independent as if it were getting a line directly to the ISP?
2. For network security, do the settings of one network depend on the other? Ex) IF I want to port forward a device on Network B, would I also have to do it on Network A or would just the once be enough?
3. Are there any inherent limitations of this setup?

Comment: “Are there any inherent limitations of this setup?” Nope. But you are creating more headaches for you down the line. Especially if you are doing this with consumer grade routers and switches and such. Unless there is a true reason you need a setup like this, don’t go down this road.

Comment: You are missing one question: (4) Is it a good idea to do it that way? A: No. It's an easy setup for people with consumer-grade routers, and it will work (mostly), but for anyone who's seen a proper network with subnetworks, it's a really, really horrible way to do things (starting with the double NAT). The downside of a proper network setup is that it's quite difficult to realize with the default firmware on consumer-grade routers, so most home users do end up with something like in your diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the router's regular setup (NAT) and connecting a LAN port on router A to the WAN port of router B, then everything on the second network B will apparently have (share) router B's "external" IP address. Any rules that the main router (A) has for router B will apply to everything connected to router B.

If you wanted to connect from network A to a specific device on B's network, you'd have to set up port forwarding on router B to that device. If you wanted to connect from the internet, you'd need port forwarding on router A to router B, then from router B to the specific B device.

Similarly, outgoing connections from a device in B's network that needed a special setting on router B would need a similar setting on router A too.

That's the basic limitation, and why setting up something different, like a bridged network, is a good alternative to avoid these hassles.

But as described, a device in B's  network should have perfectly fine access to the internet. It (the second router) *could* even be considered as an extra layer of security for B network devices...

Answer (score 0):

If you connect the LAN port of Router B to the LAN port of Router A, then Router B becomes the switch.

Then network B can not be said to be independent or a subnet. You can think of this as a client of Network A. The security of network B depends on the security of network A. As for the limitations, there is no in this setting.

Comment: So basically you're saying if you use the Ethernet ports that it will just be a switch, but if you connect via wifi it will then be subject to router B's network and router A's network?